# Single QTreeWidgetItem instance on multiple QTreeWidget?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyside, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I'm trying to show a single `QTreeWidgetItem` instance on 2 `QTreeWidget`s, which ends up the item shown only on the 1st tree without being notified. I haven't seen [its API doc](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtreewidgetitem.html) talks about a limitation if any. Is there a way to workaround?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys  

from PySide.QtCore import QFile
from PySide.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QWidget

class MyTreeWidgetItem(QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, *args):  
       super(MyTreeWidgetItem, self).__init__()

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):  
       super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

       loader = QUiLoader()
       file = QFile('./src/prove_qtreewidget/qtree_mainwidget.ui') 
       file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
       self.widget_ui = loader.load(file, self)
       file.close()

       item1 = MyTreeWidgetItem(self)
       item1.setText(0, 'Item 1')

       _tw1 = self.widget_ui.findChild(QTreeWidget, '_tree_widget_1')
       _tw2 = self.widget_ui.findChild(QTreeWidget, '_tree_widget_2')
       _tw1.addTopLevelItem(item1)
       _tw2.addTopLevelItem(item1)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
   print("Running in " + os.getcwd() + " .\n")    
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)      
   win = MyWidget()  
   win.show()    
   app.exec_()
```

`.ui` file above is available [here](http://pastebin.com/SjWQQWg6).

Using Qt 4.8, Ubuntu 12.04

I haven't tried `PyQt` binding but I just assume shouldn't be any different w/o proof.

Comment: No. A `QTreeWidgetItem` can belong to only one `QTreeWidget`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I appreciate if you could share a documentation if any about the limit. I'm trying to show a data that I already implemented with QTreeWidgetItem in multiple different trees for different purpose. I know QTreeView fits more for this purpose but I've already implemented non-trivial amount of code..

Comment: It doesn't say that explicitly (or I couldn't find it) but if you were to add it to multiple tree widgets, `item.treeWidget()` would be undefined. You're right, model/view is more appropriate if you want to share same model between views. If not, all you can do is add a copy of your item. `item_copy = QTreeWidgetItem(item)` will do that for you. If you have custom items, you can implement a `copy` method that uses this underneath.

Comment: That being said, I'd really suggest that you convert to `QTreeView`. It might be time consuming to convert your current code base, but if you are going to do anything non-trivial it would possibly be better in the long-run.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [model and a `QTreeView`](http://pepper.troll.no/s60prereleases/doc/model-view-introduction.html), that's for what they are for:

> **Model/View Programming:** Widgets do not maintain internal data containers. They access external data through a standardized interface and therefore avoid data duplication.

Comment: As in the comment area of the original question, I know Qt's MVC implementation but don't want to use it for this particular purpose.